# Find value(s) in array where some elements have multiple dimensions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that can contain multidimensional elements. For populating checkboxes from database in the edit-form, I need to check for specific key-value pairs from this array.

The array ($areastools) can look like this:

```
array:9 [▼
 15 => array:2 [▼
      0 => 1
      1 => 4
 16 => 4
 45 => array:2 [▶]
 47 => 4
 50 => array:2 [▶]
 51 => 4
]
```

The first key is the specific area id ($area->pivot->id), and the values are the tool ids ($tool->id).

Currently I have this check, where the checkbox is checked if

```
(array_key_exists($area->pivot->id, $areastools) && 
($areastools[$area->pivot->id] == $tool->id))
```

This works for all elements of the array that are not multidimensional. The correct checkboxes are then checked in the edit-form.

But when two tools are added to the same area, the checkboxes for none of these tools are checked, as the condition does not check the values correct if an area has many tools.

I have been searching and trying, but can not find out how to do this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you try to check if value is array? Check manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make a little function. Not very elegant, but it works.

```
function areaTools($areaTools, $areaId, $toolId) {
    if(array_key_exists($areaId, $areaTools) {
        if(is_array($areaTools[$areaId]) {
            foreach($areaTools[$areaId] as $tool) {
                if($tool == $toolId;) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return $areaTools[$areaId] == $toolId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works flawlessly :) I have been struggling with this for a very long time, so although I had to ask for help the joy is still great when seeing it working :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to know if a certain key-value pair is found, use [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
$found=0;
function find_key_value($v, $k)
{
    global $area,$tool,$found;
    if (($k==$area->pivot->id)&&($v==$tool->id))
         $found=1;
}
array_walk_recursive($areastools, 'find_key_value');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have not used this function before, and I got some error when trying to implement it (illegal offset). I will look into the function later, but I got the form working with the function mentioned in the above answer for now.